# Функция меняет словарь, не понятно как?

Tags: python-3.x, область-видимости

Есть кусок кода:

```
group_req = {
    'token' : token,
    'request' : []
    }

group_1 = group_req.copy()

group_2 = group_req.copy()

def meke_group_requests(group, val):
    for reg in val:
        tmp_request = {
                'region' : reg,
                'firstname' : client[1],
                'secondname' : client[2],
                'lastname' : client[0],
                'birthdate' : client[3]
                }
        group['request'].append(tmp_request)

meke_group_requests(group_1, num_region_1)
```

Подскажите как выполнение meke_group_requests меняет словарь group_req?
Не могу понять никак

Comment: А как оно меняет? Обратите внимание на `.copy()`

Answer (score 3):

Метод .copy() производит лишь поверхностное копирование. https://thispointer.com/python-how-to-copy-a-dictionary-shallow-copy-vs-deep-copy/
Тебе поможет функция deepcopy из модуля copy

```
import copy
group_1 = copy.deepcopy(group_req)
```